Column-level encryption failing when trying to encrypt files
Environment

SQL Server 2016 Standard
PHP 8.2

Background
I have column-level encryption set up and fully functioning for a number of columns. My database is successfully interfacing with clients through PHP.
Issue
I can't get column-level encryption working when trying to store a file.  I had it fully working prior to encryption with the following (simplified) code:
PHP:
$filePath = $_FILES["file_ToUpload"]["tmp_name"];       
// Read the file into a binary variable
$fileData = file_get_contents($filePath);
$fileData = unpack('H*hex', $fileData); // Convert binary data to hex
$fileData = $fileData['hex'];

// Prepare the SQL query
$query = "{CALL spUploadFile(?)}";
$params = array(
    $fileData
);
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $params);

The SQL procedure:
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUploadFile]
    @FileData NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @BinaryData VARBINARY(MAX) = CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), @FileData, 2);  -- Convert hex string back to binary
    
    INSERT INTO MyFiles (File_Data)
    VALUES (@BinaryData)
END

My attempts
I feel like I've tried everything.  I've tried passing the $filedata as binary within PHP.  Here's what I thought would be most successful within my SQL procedure:
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUploadFile]
    @FileData NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN  
    OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY MY_SymmetricKey
    DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE MY_ColumnEncryption;
    
    Declare @EncryptedFileData VARBINARY(MAX) = ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('MY_SymmetricKey'), @FileData)
    
    CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY MY_SymmetricKey;
    
    INSERT INTO MyFiles (File_Data)
    VALUES (@EncryptedFileData) 
END

However, this throws there error:  String or Binary data will be truncated.  I also tried:
Declare @EncryptedFileData VARBINARY(MAX) = ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('MY_SymmetricKey'), convert(varchar(MAX), @FileData))

With the same results.  A .txt file works fine, but most others don't.
Attempting passing the file as a byte array also gave the truncation error:
PHP:
$filePath = $_FILES["file_ToUpload"]["tmp_name"];       
// Read the file into a binary variable
$fileData = file_get_contents($filePath);

// Prepare the SQL query
$query = "{CALL spUploadFile(array($fileData, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN, SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STREAM(SQLSRV_ENC_BINARY), SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_VARBINARY('max'))}";
$params = array(
    $fileData
);
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $params);

SQL:
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUploadFile]
    @FileData VARBINARY(MAX)
AS
BEGIN  
    OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY MY_SymmetricKey
    DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE MY_ColumnEncryption;
    
    Declare @EncryptedFileData VARBINARY(MAX) = ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('MY_SymmetricKey'), @FileData)
    
    CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY MY_SymmetricKey;
    
    INSERT INTO MyFiles (File_Data)
    VALUES (@EncryptedFileData)
END


You get the truncation error because ENCRYPTBYKEY has an output limit of 8000 bytes:

Return Types
varbinary with a maximum size of 8,000 bytes.
Returns NULL if the key is not open, if the key does not exist, or if the key is a deprecated RC4 key and the database is not in compatibility level 110 or higher.
Returns NULL if the cleartext value is NULL.

To work around this, you could use custom T-SQL functions to encrypt and decrypt in blocks. See for example SQL Server 2005 Encryption – Encryption and data length limitations. You could also use the file system, a SQLCLR implementation or perform the encryption and decryption in the application.
